# f(x) is triple differentiable, derivatives of f(xˆ2)

Tags: derivatives

Let f(x) is a triple differentiable function. How to find the 2d and 3d derivatives of f(xˆ2)?

How should I start approaching these question?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first derivative is given by $$f'(x^2)\cdot 2x$$ using the chain rule
and the second derivative by $$f''(x^2)\cdot (2x)^2+f'(x^2)\cdot 2$$
and further
$$f'''(x^2)\cdot (2x)^3+f''(x^2)\cdot 2(2x)\cdot 2+f''(x^2)\cdot 2x\cdot 2$$

Comment: should i post you the third derivative for your Control?

Comment: I would appreciate:) Thank you!